# validation sync issue between grid and form on kendo ui

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

http://dojo.telerik.com/IRaJU/2

Using this link, I operate an input validation on the ProductName field on both the form and grid.
While the inputs on the form and grid are synchronized on any input that doesn't "wrongInput" , when i insert the value "wrongInput" , which the validation returns false on it , the values are not synchronized.
For example: if I enter the value "val" , on grid , it changes also on the form.
but on the value "wrongInput" , it changes only on the grid , because it doesn't meet the validation criteria.

Can someone please help how to make the input on the form and grid to be synchronized , when I enter the value "wrongInput".